# VBScript: Occasional ActiveX can't create Matlab application error

Tags: matlab, vbscript, activex

I have a VBScript that is automatically triggered from another program (called "ATCS") about 30 times a day.  The sole purpose of the VBScript is to execute a Matlab script (necessary because it seems to be impossible to execute the Matlab  script directly from ATCS).  The VBScript works properly about 95% of the time, but about 5% of the time, it fails with this error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Matlab.Application'

Here are the contents of my VBScript:

`Set MatLab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application") 
MatLab.Execute("cd('C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\MATLAB')")
Matlab.Execute("UpdateOliveTime")`

In my searches to try to find the solution to this problem, I have found that this "ActiveX component can't create object" error has been asked about before.  However, in every previous question I could find, the problem seemed to be a fundamental issue that caused the VBScript to fail 100% of the time, which is quite different from my situation, where it usually works but fails about 5% of the time.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible that the Matlab.Application object already exists?  That is - it has not closed from a previous instance.

Comment: It is possible that the previous instance is sometimes still open when it tries to  run it again.  Would that cause this sort of failure?  Is there any way around that?

Comment: I am not really an expert on MatLab, but that is where I would be looking to start with.  Could you could run a check (via a script) for running processes prior to executing your script?